# start_on parameter is not giving correct results in expresionengine

Tags: php, expressionengine

I have a channel to manage events and I'm facing a problem when I want to implement some common operations like displaying past events. If I want to see the current and future events I assumed I can get it in the following way:

> {exp:channel:entries channel="events" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="no" orderby="{date}" sort="asc" dynamic="no" start_on=""}

where $entry_date is in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM (ex: 2011-08-02 11:00)

It should display the events in this order:

```
2012-08-02 11:00
2012-09-02 11:00
2012-10-02 11:00
2012-11-02 11:00
```

But it's displaying them without including the event at 2012-08-02 11:00 (seems the comparison EE does is >, not >=)

And also the past events (which are marked like expired already)I organized and display them by year:

{exp:channel:entries channel="events" show_future_entries="no" show_expired="yes" orderby="{date}" sort="desc" dynamic="no" year="" start_on=""}

assuming my past events are:

```
2011-08-02 11:00
2011-09-02 11:00
2011-10-02 11:00
2011-11-02 11:00
```

and $entry_date = 2011-10-02 11:00

It should display something like this:

```
2011-10-02 11:00
2011-09-02 11:00
2011-08-02 11:00
```

and its displaying it in a incorrect order.

In fact the problems are:

1. For current and future events, the event = start_on parameter is not included in the results.
2. For past events, its displaying the events in a wrong order (the oldest event is the first one in being displayed).

Can somebody tell me if there is something wrong with my code?

I'm using EE 2.4.0 and php is enable at the input in the templates where I try to do those operations.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I see here.

`orderby="{date}"` should actually be `orderby="date"` (or it can be
    omitted entirely, since date/entry_date is the default orderby).

Your issue with the upcoming events may be the way you're generating
    your `$entry_date` variable. Can you tell me how that's being created
    exactly? Are you echoing it out somewhere to make sure it is in fact
    what you think it is? You could be encountering localization
    differences between EE and your server. If you indeed have an entry
    with the exact same entry date as what you out in `start_on`, it
    *should* appear. Try putting the date in `start_on` manually to troubleshoot.

For your past events, you should be using  `stop_before`, not `start_on`. These two parameters do not pay heed to your `sort` parameter - they are always based on chronology.